# TimeSeriesAggregate—reformatting the date

Tags: date-and-time, time-series

[Compute Aggregated Statistics for a Time Series](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/time-series/compute-aggregated-statistics-for-a-time-series.html)

The article linked to above provides a sample of aggregating time series data.

```
ts = FinancialData["NYSE:GS", "Price", {{2012, 1, 1}, {2013, 1, 1}}];
total = TimeSeriesAggregate[data, "Quarter", Total];
```

Interrogating `total` returns the following absolute time format for the aggregated date field.

> `{3538468800, 6738.89}`

Is it possible to reformat the absolute time back into a mmm-yy format, which is representative of the month or quarter that the date relates to?

Answer (score 2):

```
ts = FinancialData["NYSE:GS", "Price", {{2012, 1, 1}, {2013, 1, 1}}];

total = TimeSeriesAggregate[ts, "Quarter", Total];
```

Note that you need `ts` rather than `data` in definition of `total`

```
(total2 = 
   MapAt[DateString[#, {"MonthNameShort", "-", "YearShort"}] &@*
     DateList, total, {All, 1}]) // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can reformat the absolute very easily and you have almost any format that you want. Look at [`DateString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html) for the large range of date and time element formats available.

Here is a function that will handle your data.

```
toDateString[{arg1_, arg2_}, fmt_] := {DateString[arg1, fmt], arg2}
```

Examples

```
With[{
    item = {3538468800, 6738.89},
    fmt = {"MonthNameShort", "-", "YearShort"}}, 
  toDateString[item, fmt]]
```

> `{"Feb-12", 6738.89}`

```
ts = FinancialData["NYSE:GS", "Price", {{2012, 1, 1}, {2013, 1, 1}}];
total = TimeSeriesAggregate[ts, "Quarter", Total];
With[{fmt = {"QuarterNameShort", "-", "Year"}},
  toDateString[#, fmt] & /@ total]
```

> `{{"Q1-2012", 6738.89}, {"Q2-2012", 6141.51}, 
>   {"Q3-2012", 6392.01}, {"Q4-2012", 6893.01}}`